# Sort array based on its object's value which contains a timestamp

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

First I create 2 different queries.

```
$first = first::where('id',$request->first_id)->select('name','created_at')->get();
$second = second::where('id', $request->second_id)->select('name','created_at')->get();
```

I then merge the two resulting arrays.

```
$data_combine = array_merge($first->toArray(), $second->toArray());
```

Finally, I'd like to sort the combined arrays in ascending order based on their `created_at` value, e.g '2016-05-06 16:43:46'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array_values(array_sort($data_combine , function ($value) {
    return $value['created_at'];
}));
```

You can sort your merged array using array_sort function.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/helpers#arrays

Comment: does this work in Laravel 5.0? I'm not on 5.1 yet sadly.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this easily with Laravel Collection methods. Unlike a regular array, with a Collection you'll still have access to all the other helpful collection methods Laravel makes available on Models.

You can merge your arrays into a new collection and then sort that collection.

`collect(array_merge($first -> toArray(), $second -> toArray())) -> sortBy('created_at');`

A more fluent way of writing the above would also work

`$first -> push($second) -> flatten() -> sortBy('created_at');`

For this to work `created_at` needs to be visible. If not already defined as such in your Model's visible property (and safe to do so) you'd need to add that first. Otherwise, you'd need to loop the initial collections and run `addVisible('created_at')` to make it visible for your current result.

Comment: does not sort in seconds difference. Any ideas?

Comment: Good point @Ankit - they need to be arrays merged into a collection instead. Correcting the logic as above should now sort correctly.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `toArray()`, because Collection have `all()` method:

`$combine = collect(array_merge($first->all(), $second->all()))->sortByDesc("created_at");`

If you have only one element in the both arrays, can try:

`$combine = collect([$first->first(), $second->first()])->sortByDesc("created_at");`